# Browser Back Button stillm redirecting to previous page after using middleware

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I tried this method of using middleware as seen on google but the browser back button still directs me to the previous page. I have tried almost all the solutions on google related to this but have not yet found a solution. Could you help me please? I created a custom login form and did exactly what the people on google had told me to regarding the middleware but im still redirected to the previous page

My middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PreventBackHistory
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
   
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)

    {

        $response = $next($request);

        return $response->header('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')

            ->header('Pragma','no-cache')

            ->header('Expires','Sun, 02 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');

    }
}
```

My kernel:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,

    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'revalidate' => \App\Http\Middleware\RevalidateBackHistory::class,
        'prevent-back-history' => \App\Http\Middleware\PreventBackHistory::class,
    ];
}
```

My routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['prevent-back-history']], function () {
    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/home',[TemplateController::class,'home'])->name('homepost.list');

});
```

Comment: Hello! What is it you are trying to accomplish? Forget about the advice from google and prior attempts to solve this - what is your goal? Are you wanting to stop the back button from ever working when on your site?

Answer (score 0):

try this one. It will disable the back button of your browser

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        window.history.pushState(null, "", window.location.href);        
        window.onpopstate = function() {
            window.history.pushState(null, "", window.location.href);
        };
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sandip but it did not work

Comment: i put it in my layouts page within script tags but it did not work